OOM for query execution
We are running into OOM when we run large number of SQL queries. We are using Apache Ignite 2.15. Pretty standard query code like below,
SqlFieldsQuery sqlQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery(query);
if (args != null) {
    sqlQuery.setArgs(args);
}
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sqlQuery);

Doing the heap analysis indicated, "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.RunningQueryManager" having a map which maintains references of all the running queries. But does not seem to clean up the map post query execution.
On trying to look this up further, we found references to the same issue but no activity,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13130
Apache Ignite : Ignite on-heap cache occupying too much memory in heap. Causing the application to throw OutOfMemory exception
Any help appreciated.

Do you close the query cursor? (It's autoclosable. Generally best to use in a try-resource block.)

Yes after the data is retrieved.

I think you'd need to create a reproducer. Pretty much everyone using Ignite runs SQL queries, so it's unlikely to be a leak when running any query.

On further debugging this as i was creating a reproducer. Found a deep hidden reference to cursor that wasn't closed. On closing that reference this issue was solved. Thanks.
